# How to observe changes in database in order to update LiveData

Tags: android, viewmodel, contentobserver, mutablelivedata

I am migrating an app from a `LoaderManager` with `Callbacks` to an implementation using `ViewModel` and `LiveData`. I would like to keep using the existing `SQLiteDatabase`.

The main implementation works OK. The `Activity` instantiates the `ViewModel` and creates an `Observer` which updates the `View` if it observes changes in the `MutableLiveData` that lives in the `ViewModel`. The `ViewModel` gets it data (cursor) from the `SQLiteDatabase` through a query using a `ContentProvider`.

But I have other activities that can make changes to the database, while `MainActivity` is stopped but not destroyed. There is also a background service that can make changes to the database while the `MainActivity` is on the foreground.

Other activities and the background service can change values in the database and therefore can have an effect to the `MutableLiveData` in the `ViewModel`.

My question is: How to observe changes in the `SQLiteDatabase` in order to update `LiveData`?

This is a simplified version of `MainActivity`:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private DrawerAdapter mDrawerAdapter;
    HomeActivityViewModel homeActivityViewModel;

    private Observer<Cursor> leftDrawerLiveDataObserver = new Observer<Cursor>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable Cursor cursor) {
            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) { // Do we have a non-empty cursor?
                mDrawerAdapter.setCursor(cursor);
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        homeActivityViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(HomeActivityViewModel.class);
        homeActivityViewModel.getLiveData().observe(this, leftDrawerLiveDataObserver);
        homeActivityViewModel.updateLiveData(); //,LEFT_DRAWER_LIVEDATA_ID);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume(){  // update the LiveData on Resume
        super.onResume();
        homeActivityViewModel.updateLiveData();
    }
}
```

This is my `ViewModel`:

```
public class HomeActivityViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

    public HomeActivityViewModel(Application application) {
        super(application);
    }

    @NonNull
    private final MutableLiveData<Integer> updateCookie = new MutableLiveData<>();

    @NonNull
    private final LiveData<Cursor> cursorLeftDrawer =
            Transformations.switchMap(updateCookie,
                    new Function<Integer, LiveData<Cursor>>() {
                        private QueryHandler mQueryHandler;

                        @Override
                        public LiveData<Cursor> apply(Integer input) {
                            mQueryHandler = new QueryHandler(getApplication().getContentResolver());
                            MutableLiveData<Cursor> cursorMutableLiveData = new MutableLiveData<>();
                            mQueryHandler.startQuery(ID, cursorMutableLiveData, URI,
                                new String[]{FeedData.ID, FeedData.URL},
                                null,null,null
                            );
                            return cursorMutableLiveData;
                        }
                    }
            );

    // By changing the value of the updateCookie, LiveData gets refreshed through the Observer.
    void updateLiveData() {
        Integer x = updateCookie.getValue();
        int y = (x != null) ? Math.abs(x -1) : 1 ;
        updateCookie.setValue(y);
    }

    @NonNull
    LiveData<Cursor> getLiveData() {
        return cursorLeftDrawer;
    }

    /**
     * Inner class to perform a query on a background thread.
     * When the query is completed, the result is handled in onQueryComplete
     */
    private static class QueryHandler extends AsyncQueryHandler {
        QueryHandler(ContentResolver cr) {
            super(cr);
        }
        @Override
        protected void onQueryComplete(int token, Object cookie, Cursor cursor) {
            MutableLiveData<Cursor> cursorMutableLiveData = (MutableLiveData<Cursor>) cookie;
                             cursorMutableLiveData.setValue(cursor);

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: probably using https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/ContentObserver (and notifying in the contentresolver! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24465999/content-resolver-notifychange-not-working)

Comment: That maybe a good way to go ahead. I will look into that a bit further. Thanks!

Comment: I implemented a simple `ContentObserver` and it works like a charm. Thanks for your help! @zapl

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should take a look `Room`. A Room database uses SQLite in the background and will automatically notify your `LiveData` objects when any changes have been made in the database. Thus you never need to worry about queries and cursors and so on. 
Take a look at this [tutorial](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view/#0)!

Comment: Thanks. I will definitely look into `Room`. Unfortunately, this is an existing app with a rather complex contentprovider and database. 

Android deprecated the `CursorLoaders` (which worked perfectly fine btw), so I was thinking to migrate to ViewModels first and keep the app up-and-running. After that, I can take steps to implement `Room`.

Comment: Alright, in that case ContentObserver might work better :)